# Graph Theory Logic

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

So, I have this graph theory question saying that "A graph G had 6 vertices and their degrees are 2d,2d,2d+1,2d+1,2d+1 and 3d-1, show that d must be even using the sum of the edges." Now it obviously adds them up to show 13d+2=Sum of Edges, and then states d must be even, Im at a loss on how this is worked out?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a graph with no loops or parallel edges: The sum of degrees of the vertices is twice the number of edges [since each edge contributes to two vertex degrees], so must be even. So if the degree sum is $13d+2$ in your example, it means $13d+2$ is even, so also $13d$ is even, finally that $d$ is even [Since 13 is odd, if $d$ were odd then $13d$ would be odd].

*Added Later:* It is implied you're considering undirected graphs [otherwise separate concepts of indegree/outdegree would occur rather than simply degree of a vertex]. And I should also point out that existence of parallel edges or loops will still make an even vertex degree sum, since each non-loop edge still contributes 1 to both vertex counts of the vertices at its ends, and a loop contributes 2 to the vertex it is at.